# Strange behaviour with %sysfunc, cat and '<>' (SAS Macro)

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I am trying to concatenate with '<' and '>'. However, I am getting 0 digits as output instead:

```
74   %let mname = ABC;
75   %put &mname;
ABC
76   %let mname2 = %sysfunc(cat(&mname., <, 2, >));
77   %put &mname2;
ABC020
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: I think you are asking the same qustion just as I asked 1 minutes ago.

Comment: Haha! yeah, I tried using %>, %< to escape. None of that works too :(

Comment: I tried `%str()`, `%quote()`, `%bquote()` even `%superq()`, they are all useless. I have to use \u003e to replace ">" temporarily and hope I would find the answer as soon as possible.

Comment: Why would you ever %SYSFUNC() to call CAT()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `%sysfunc(cat(...))` in macro.  Use a literal macro concatenation instead

```
%let mname3 = &mname.<2>;
%put NOTE: &=mname3;
```

It appears the root cause of your observation is that `%sysfunc` is performing an implicit evaluation (either `%eval` or `%sysevalf`) of the resolved macro arguments before invoking `cat`.  The bare `<` is evaluated to `0` (`%put %eval(<);` confirms this).  A bare `=` would get evaluated to `1`

Comment: It may not be `%sysfunc()`, @Richard. I tried this `%let x=%sysfunc(coalescec(y>80,xx)); %put &=x;` and just get `X=y>80`. I think the reason may related to the `cat*()` functions.

Comment: Thanks Richard! I did not know you could do literal concatenation with macro variables.

Comment: FYI, I also tried `%let y = %sysfunc(compress(&x.,<>))` with `%let x=ABC<2>`. `%put &y.` outputs `ABC2`. So yeah there is something with cat() that is not working.